# Evaluating $\frac{\operatorname d \! \phantom x}{\operatorname d\!x}\frac{4}{\ln(x^2+2)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

$\dfrac{\operatorname d \! \phantom x}{\operatorname d\!x}\dfrac{4}{\ln(x^2+2)}= \dfrac{4}{\ln u}$

$u=x^2+2$
$u\;'=2x$

$y\;'=\dfrac{4}{\dfrac{1}{u}} \times (u\;') \implies \dfrac{4}{\dfrac{1}{x^2+2}}(2x) \implies (4x^2+8)(2x)=8x^3+16x$

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-write the equation as
$$y=4(\ln(x^2+2))^{-1}$$
Then use the chain rule and the power rule.

Let $u=x^2+2$, so $u'=2x$. Now you have
$$y=4(\ln(u))^{-1}$$
This is just the power rule.

Let $v=\ln(u)$. Now you have
$$y=4v^{-1}$$
$y'$ is just
$$-1(v')4v^{-2}$$
$v'$ is just
$$\frac{u'}{u}$$
which is
$$\frac{2x}{x^2+2}$$
Put this all together and you have (answer is hidden under a "spoiler" - mouse over to see)

> $$y'=\frac{-8x}{(x^2+2)(\ln(x^2+2))^2}$$

Comment: I think there should be an x in the numerator.

Comment: @SherlockHolmes Dang, you're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is wrong because when you differentiate with respect to u, you get:

$\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} u}(\frac{4}{\ln u})=\frac{\frac{-4}{u}}{(\ln u)^2}=\frac{-4}{u(\ln u)^2}=\frac{-4}{(x^2+2)(\ln (x^2+2))^2}$

Applying the chain rule by multiplying with $\frac{\mathrm{du} }{\mathrm{d} x}=2x$, we get the answer of $\frac{-8x}{(x^2+2)(\ln (x^2+2))^2}$

Answer (score 1):

. Put $v = \ln u$, and $u = x^2 + 2$.

$\dfrac{df}{dv} \left(\dfrac{4}{v}\right) = -\dfrac{4}{v^2}$,

$\dfrac{dv}{du} = \dfrac{1}{u}$

$\dfrac{du}{dx} = 2x$. Thus by the Chainrule:

$\dfrac{df}{dx} = \dfrac{df}{dv}\cdot \dfrac{dv}{du}\cdot \dfrac{du}{dx} = -\dfrac{4}{v^2}\cdot \dfrac{1}{u}\cdot 2x = \dfrac{-4}{\ln^2 (x^2+2)}\cdot \dfrac{1}{x^2+2}\cdot 2x = \dfrac{-8x}{(x^2+2)\ln^2 (x^2+2)}$